# Django: may not be NULL when submitting a form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to submit a form with just the date(and now time), but when I go to submit it I get the error `incidents_incident.incident_date_time_occurred may not be NULL` even when I enter an actual date in the input field. Why do I get that error when I enter in a date?

**models.py**

```
class Incident(models.Model):
       incident_date_time_occurred = models.DateTimeField('incident occurred', default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    class Meta:
               verbose_name_plural="Incident"
```

**forms.py**

```
class IncidentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Incident
        fields = ('incident_date_time_occurred',)
```

**report.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container-fluid">

<form action="{% url 'incidents:report' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="date" class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{ form.incident_date_time_occurred.label }}</label>
            <input type="datetime-local" name= "incident_date_time_occurred" class="form-control" id="date">
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Inschrijven!" class="btn btn-primary" />

</form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: try adding models.DateTimeField('incident occurred', default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)

Comment: They are entering the date though. It should not be interpreting it as null.

Comment: I'm confused. I want to require the user to enter the date and right now even when I enter the date I still get the error above.

Comment: ohhh yes, its a datetimefield, you need to make it DateField

Comment: Where is the name of the field in your form? `input` should hold a name.

Comment: i'm not sure I follow. The name is in the label. Should I use `name` instead of 'id'?

Comment: `<input type="date" name="incident_date_time_occurred" class="form-control" id="date">`

Comment: I've made edits above. I'm still getting the error. I just don't understand, because I'm putting correctly formatted data in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your solution by using default form created from incident? As I remember Django's dateTimeField requires two fields: date and time.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `name` attribute on the date input. Try that:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="incident_date_time_occurred">
```